# How to elegantly evaluate if user input has numbers only in it using an if statement in Python?

Tags: python

I feel like this should be obvious, I've done this before even as a beginner but I just can't seem to write it in any way that isn't a horror to look at and Google searches aren't turning up anything useful (because I have no idea how to word this as a search)

Comment: What do you mean "has numbers only"? Particularly, which of these have numbers only: A) "1234" b) "1234 1234" c) "-1234" ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
myinput = input()  # in Python 2.x use raw_input()

if myinput.isdigit():
    ...
```

Comment: Note that that will not recognize negatives or floats. Also input is not recommended you should use raw_input

Comment: @yuvi Those don't seem to be part of the requirement.

Comment: You're right, but he seems like a beginner, I just thought it would be helpful to mention that

Comment: @yuvi Exactly, so why confuse him with things he doesn't need? Also note that in Python 3.x `raw_input()` was replaced by `input()`. I did make a note that in 2.x `raw_input()` should be used.

Comment: there's nothing confusing about explaining the limits and capabilities of a function, especially if it's a very basic one. As for the input- yeah I saw, but at the time the comment system did not let me edit it out (and now I can't at all).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [isdigit()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

```
foo = 1
bar = "2ab3*#"

str(foo).isdigit() # True
str(bar).isdigit() # False
```

Answer (score 1):

With using the try-except syntax, you do not have to modify your existing code for the case of non-numeric input.

```
try:
    a=int(input)                # or a=float(input) if decimals are allowed
    # perform your calculation here with a
except ValueError:
    print 'You did not enter a number'
```